# Не работает чтение и запись в файл Qt

Tags: c++, qt, файлы

Есть окно, в окне кнопка и лейбл. код кнопки

```
void HelloWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QFile fileOut("data.txt");

    QString name=ui->pushButton->text();

    if(fileOut.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)){
           QTextStream stream(&fileOut);
           QString str=stream.readAll();
           ui->label->setText(str);
       }
    else
        QMessageBox::information(this,"error","ERROR!");
    fileOut.close();
}
```

В фаиле data.txt есть некая строчка. Кьют не выдает месседжбокс об ошибке, то есть чтение произошло и с ним все окей, но текст на лейбле присваивается пустоте, то есть он не смог прочитать из фаила. С записью так же - ошибки нет, но кьют ничего не записывает. Из-за чего это и как исправить?

Comment: дебаггер что говорит на эту тему?

Comment: Для ошибок у `QMessageBox` есть статический метод [critical](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#critical)

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке не выдается, если файл удалось __открыть__, а не прочесть. Вам бы поставить бряк на крайней строчке тела if'а и посмотреть, что оказалось в `str`.

Answer (score 2):

Создал аналогичный пример:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFile fileOut("data.txt");

    if(fileOut.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)){
        QTextStream stream(&fileOut);
        QString str=stream.readAll();
        qDebug() << str;
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "error";
    fileOut.close();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Он полностью отработал. Проверьте расположение файла. Он должен лежать рядом с исполняемым файлом, либо попробуйте прописать полный путь до него. Также посмотрите включена ли теневая сборка. При включенной теневой сборке бинарники собираются в отдельной директории.